# On a low gravity planet, as a pedestrian, would having more mass be an advantage?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Say this planet (or body since it would be too small to be classified as a planet) has a gravity of 0.1g or less.  Perhaps any small force (bumping into another human) could cause you to fly off the ground, making you float far distances.  This would be a huge inconvenience.

Would weighing yourself down via a suit, maybe enough to simulate 1g be an advantage?  Could there even be a celestial body where gravity is low enough, that gently pushing someone would be an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are heavier than the other humans, then indeed the additional gravitational force would be an advantage. However, if all the humans do the same thing, bumping into them will generate a proportionally higher force, and it won't help you. Except, perhaps, that the heavier people will tend to move more slowly.

If you could weigh down just the shoes (like the old diving suits) you might improve the situation a little: the force of the "bump" would be with the lighter part of you (less impact), while the force of gravity would still be increased.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct, in a planet with very low gravity any force in an upwards direction could even push you away for the planet forever, if the force applied is enough for you to reach the planet's scape velocity. This of course would be a problem. How do you gain resistance against pushed? well, either by increasing the planet's gravity, or just by increasing your mass. So you are right, heavy suits would be enough to overcome this issue.